# using cx_freeze to make an executable python program from multiple python scripts

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm, openpyxl, cx-freeze

i started to use cx_freeze to make my project to an executable after failing with pyinstaller,
i'm using tkinter to make a GUI and the main.py GUI is working and when the 2nd script GUI in suppose to initialize it only initialize the window, but without the menu or any dependencies from tkinter such as slider bars, labels or entry boxes

my setup.py configured this way:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable


includefiles = ['Doctor.xlsx']
includes = []
excludes = []
packages = ['tkinter', 'openpyxl']
build_exe_options = {'includes': includes, 'packages': packages, 'excludes': excludes, 'include_files': includefiles}

base = None
if sys.platform == 'win64':
    base = 'Win64GUI'
elif sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

exe = Executable(
    script="Main.py",
    target_name="AutoDoctor",
    base = base
)
setup(
    name="AutoDoctor",
    version="1.0",
    description="Program to diagnose blood results and generate a matching treatment.",
    options={'build_exe': build_exe_options},
    executables=[exe],
)
```

In the project i have multiple scripts:  `Main.py, Diagnosis.py, Database.py`
from my understanding the Database.py working well because the Main.py script is using the Database from the Database.py script.

Comment: `Database.py`? is that a python file? and you only named it as Database?

Comment: @JoeMo just a file i named Database, i used openpyxl to import an Excel file as a database

Comment: `cxfreeze yourfile.py --target -dir-cx` you tried this? you instaled cx?

Comment: @JoeMo didn't try this, should i try this in the project directory or from python directory?

Answer (score 0):

if you are on windows, you can do this from desktop. but if you want to be sure. go to your directory and do this: [image]

open the cmd and put this code in. make sure that you have installed what you need

Comment: i tried that,
'cxfreeze' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file...
even though it is installed in the project venv scripts

Comment: you changed `yourfile.py` to your py file? sry for that question, because for me it works.

Comment: of course, the problem in this operation is that cxfreeze isn't recognized so it doesn't even matter what py file is written after cxfreeze

Comment: hmm. i have found a guide. sorry for that. Don't know why you have this problems. try this: https://pythonprogramming.net/converting-python-scripts-exe-executables/

Comment: i checked out that guide, its basic convering py to exe guide, it isn't relevant to my problem..

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it was my code that had the problem
in my code i destroyed the main window and only then initialized the second function window so it just was an order of function problem.